# Zero Results in division teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I try to divide to decimal columns
But keeps returns zeros if after casting to decimal

For example

A         B
677.00   900.00

A/B

Returns 0.000

I try to divide to decimal columns
But keeps returns zeros if after casting to decimal

For example

A         B
677.00   900.00

A/B

Returns 0.000

expecting
0.67

Comment: Well for me it return .75, not .67.  But funny math aside, how are your columns defined?

Comment: What client / which driver are you using to connect? This could possibly be a client issue if none of the suggestions here help you.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value after the decimal then try the following query. Where 2 represents the decimal values you would like to return: -

```
SELECT CAST(A AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) / CAST(B AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) (DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS Result
FROM Table_Name;
```

Comment: Tried it but still returns 0.00

Comment: @Ghaida -  You don't even need all of those casts - `select cast(600 as decimal(10,2)) / 900` returns `0.67`.  Please update your post with sample data (in a volatile table would be best) and your query.